# Exclude files from Git while keeping the changes locally

Tags: git

Lets set the following scenario:

We are a small team of developers each of us coding on their own OS (OSX and Ubuntu). Some configuration files in the application code apply to either one of the systems, while others are specific. We all share the same code base on Github, but we don't want to mix the configuration files (also to prevent unexpected behavior) and only store them locally for the specific machine that needs them.

One way would obviously be to add those directories to the git ignore file, but that way you would also exclude bugfixes to that file; it doesn't seem like a preferable solution at all.

Is there a good way to make changes to a file while making sure that it doesn't have to be excluded manually on every commit, keep the changes locally between branches and still receive "updates" for it?

Comment: In other words you want a file to be ignored by `git add` but not by `git pull`?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wanna do.

Answer (score 1):

Create and track all system-specific versions of the configuration files, e.g.:

```
project/
    config1.osx.txt
    config1.linux.txt
    config2.osx.txt
    config2.linux.txt
```

Then, each developer would create a symlink to the appropriate configuration file on their own system as appropriate:

```
$ ln -s config1.osx.txt config1.txt
$ ln -s config2.osx.txt config2.txt
```

But these symlinks would be ignored in `.gitignore` (which is, of course, also tracked):

```
# .gitignore
config1.txt
config2.txt
```

If all these extra files create clutter, they can be put into a subdirectory (e.g. "`config`"), and simply symlinked from there.

Comment: Maybe better to just make the application understand which files to load automatically, rather than having symlinks.

Comment: @johnZwinck: sure. But, except in the really unusual IDE's, presumably this configuration would have to be saved somewhere, preferably with the project, and thus you would need a configuration file, which leads to ... back where we started. Symlinks are flexible, robust, and elegant. I like symlinks.

Comment: I meant to just write logic in the program such as "If I am running on Windows, use the "Windows" configuration directory (and perhaps a "Generic" directory as a fallback).  Saying symlinks are elegant doesn't address the fact that they will need to be maintained differently on different boxes, and if copied between different types of machines, errors will result.